# Raku Ambiguous call to infix(Hyper: Dan::Series, Int)

Tags: raku

I am writing a model Series class (kinda like the one in pandas) - and it should be both Positional and Associative.

```
class Series does Positional does Iterable does Associative {
    has Array $.data is required;
    has Array $.index;

    ### Construction ###

    method TWEAK {
        # sort out data-index dependencies
        $!index = gather {
            my $i = 0;
            for |$!data -> $d {
                take ( $!index[$i++] => $d )
            }
        }.Array
    }

    ### Output ### 

    method Str {
        $!index
    }   

    ### Role Support ### 

    # Positional role support
    # viz. https://docs.raku.org/type/Positional

    method of {
        Mu  
    }   
    method elems {
        $!data.elems
    }   
    method AT-POS( $p ) { 
        $!data[$p]
    }   
    method EXISTS-POS( $p ) { 
        0 <= $p < $!data.elems ?? True !! False
    }   

    # Iterable role support
    # viz. https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterable

    method iterator {
        $!data.iterator
    }   
    method flat {
        $!data.flat
    }   
    method lazy {
        $!data.lazy
    }   
    method hyper {
        $!data.hyper
    }   

    # Associative role support
    # viz. https://docs.raku.org/type/Associative

    method keyof {
        Str(Any)
    }   
    method AT-KEY( $k ) { 
        for |$!index -> $p {
            return $p.value if $p.key ~~ $k
        }   
    }   
    method EXISTS-KEY( $k ) { 
        for |$!index -> $p {
            return True if $p.key ~~ $k
        }   
    }   

    #`[ solution attempt #1 does NOT get called
    multi method infix(Hyper: Series, Int) is default {
        die "I was called"
    }
    #]
}

my $s = Series.new(data => [rand xx 5], index => [<a b c d e>]);

say ~$s;
say $s[2];
say $s<b>;
```

So far pretty darn cool.

I can go `dd $s.hyper` and get this

```
HyperSeq.new(configuration => HyperConfiguration.new(batch => 64, degree => 1))
```

BUT (there had to be a but coming), I want to be able to do hyper math on my Series' elements, something like:

```
say $s >>+>> 2;
```

But that yields:

```
Ambiguous call to 'infix(Hyper: Dan::Series, Int)'; these signatures all match:
  (Hyper: Associative:D \left, \right, *%_)
  (Hyper: Positional:D \left, \right, *%_)
  in block <unit> at ./synopsis-dan.raku line 63
```

How can I tell my class Series not to offer the Associative hyper candidate...?

---

Note: edited example to be a runnable MRE per @raiph's comment ... I have thus left in the minimum requirements for the 3 roles in play per docs.raku.org

Comment: "Your wisdom much appreciated!" Always provide a [MRE]. (If there are unreliable results due to, say, concurrency, so the MRE seldom reproduces the problem, still provide a MRE. If there's proprietary code involved, find a way to produce a MRE without it. Etc.) MREs aren't just about making things easier for us to try answer, or making our answers better focused, or making things better for later readers -- though all those aspects *do* apply -- but because the very effort of distilling a problem is fantastic for figuring out what is going on, why something is as it is, and what the answer is.

Comment: @raiph - FYI I have now edited to an MRE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experimentation (and new directions to consider from the very helpful comments to this SO along the way), I think I have found a solution:

1. drop the `does Associative` role from the class declaration like this:

```
class Series does Positional does Iterable {...}
```

BUT

2. leave the Associative role support methods in the body of the class:

```
    # Associative role support
    # viz. https://docs.raku.org/type/Associative

    method keyof {
        Str(Any)
    }   
    method AT-KEY( $k ) { 
        for |$!index -> $p {
            return $p.value if $p.key ~~ $k
        }   
    }   
    method EXISTS-KEY( $k ) { 
        for |$!index -> $p {
            return True if $p.key ~~ $k
        }   
    }
```

This gives me the Positional and Associative accessors, and functional hyper math operators:

```
my $s = Series.new(data => [rand xx 5], index => [<a b c d e>]);

say ~$s;        #([a => 0.6137271559776396 b => 0.7942959887386045 c => 0.5768018697817604 d => 0.8964323560788711 e => 0.025740150933493577] , dtype: Num)

say $s[2];      #0.7942959887386045
say $s<b>;      #0.5768018697817604
say $s >>+>> 2; #(2.6137271559776396 2.7942959887386047 2.5768018697817605 2.896432356078871 2.0257401509334936)
```

While this feels a bit thin (and probably lacks the full set of Associative functions) I am fairly confident that the basic methods will give me slimmed down *access like a hash from a key* capability that I seek. And it no longer creates the ambiguous call.

This solution may be cheating a bit in that I know the level of compromise that I will accept ;-).

Comment: Great Q + A! :)

Answer (score 2):

## Take #1

First, an MRE with an emphasis on the M<sup>1</sup>:

```
class foo does Positional does Associative { method of {} }
sub infix:<baz> (\l,\r) { say 'baz' }
foo.new >>baz>> 42;
```

yields:

```
Ambiguous call to 'infix(Hyper: foo, Int)'; these signatures all match:
  (Hyper: Associative:D \left, \right, *%_)
  (Hyper: Positional:D \left, \right, *%_)
  in block <unit> at ./synopsis-dan.raku line 63
```

The error message shows it's A) a call to a method named `infix` with an invocant matching `Hyper`, and B) there are two methods that potentially match that call.

Given that there's no class `Hyper` in your MRE, these methods and the `Hyper` class must be either built-ins or internal details that are leaking out.

A search of the doc finds no such class. So `Hyper` is undocumented Given that the doc has fairly broad coverage these days, this suggests `Hyper` is an internal detail. But regardless, it looks like you can't solve your problem using official/documented features.

Hopefully this bad news is still better than none.<sup>2</sup>

## Take #2

Where's the fun in letting little details like "not an official feature" stop us doing what we want to do?

There's [a `core.c` module named `Hyper.pm6` in the Rakudo source repo](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core.c/Hyper.pm6).

A few seconds browsing that, and clicks on its History and Blame, and I can instantly see it really is time for me to conclude this SO answer, with a recommendation for your next move.

To wit, I suggest you start *another* SO, using this answer as its heart (but reversing my presentation order, ie *starting* by mentioning `Hyper`, and that it's not doc'd), and namechecking Liz (per `Hyper`'s History/Blame), with a link back to your Q here as its background. I'm pretty sure *that* will get you a good answer, or at least an authoritative one.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> I also tried this:

```
class foo does Positional does Associative { method of {} }
sub postfix:<bar>(\arg) { say 'bar' }
foo.new>>bar;
```

but that worked (displayed `bar`).

<sup>2</sup> If you didn't get to my Take #1 conclusion yourself, perhaps that was was because your MRE wasn't very M? If you *did* arrive at the same point (cf "solution attempt #1 does NOT get called" in your MRE) then please read and, for future SOs, take to heart, the wisdom of ["Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @raiph for your efforts --- I did consider making my MRE shorter, but decided that it was better to leave in the required methods for the roles as set out in the docs to avoid introducing side-effects dut to missing requirements.

Comment: I too have done some spelunking into Hyper.pm6 ... my conclusion was to get a debugger up (now have that in Comma CP) and insert between the a ^ >> ^ op >> ^ 2 to work out what the objects / classes in play are (since right now I am disoriented why 'is default' not effective and the mechanism to get from a method on Hyper to the Positional/Associative roles) and will also try the "new SO" route you propose....

Comment: Hi @p6steve. "why 'is default' not effective" Because nothing is trying to call an `infix` method with a `Series` invocant. The problem is about breaking a tie between candidates in `Hyper` -- outside your control. `Hyper`'s code is complex but I'm pretty sure the tie is fundamental to how it's written and you can't affect that (except perhaps via `use MONKEY; augment class Hyper {...}` hackery, but even *if* that works, it's still a hack). `Hyper`'s History/Blame show it's Liz. Imo you need to write a new simple Q that skips the complexity and grabs her attention for my `infix:<bar>` example.

Comment: "skips the complexity and grabs her attention for my `infix:<bar>` example. " (Though *also* providing a prominent link to your MRE here so she can test anything she thinks you can do.)

Comment: general update - I gave up trying to get a debugger to work because (i) I can't work out how to install it ;-(, (ii) some more fundamental reflection on @raiph comment that ```nothing is trying to call an infix method with a Series invocant``` (my riff on this is that there must be some "contact" with a Series class ... possibly via the Positional/Associative roles ... but I was unable to work out how to hook into that) and (iii) I think that I have solved the problem (see my self-Answer).

Comment: "(iii) solved the problem" I think your answer is a great resolution to this Q at the very least. 

Comment: "(ii) ... *contact with a `Series` class* ..." Yes. The `infix` method of `»+»` handling class (`Hyper`) is called with a `Series` operand. "... possibly via the `Positional`/`Associative` roles ..." Yes. The `infix` methods have those roles as their type constraints. "... unable to work out how to hook into that" (Instead you *un*hooked *out* of that by dropping the `Associative` role from `Series`.) It seems `Hyper`'s code assumes no operand is both `Positional` *and* `Associative`. I'm going to ask a Q about that.

Comment: "(i) can't work out how to install" Aiui the *paid-for* **Comma Complete** edition is supposed to provide a relatively slick commercial product experience, with the necessary bits for debugging, profiling, etc and some bonus valuable extras automatically bundled/built/installed. And I presume it is also more QAd. But we as a community, and the Comma devs too, need the *free* **Comma Community** edition experience to be an OK one, *including adding profiling/debugging*. So please consider emailing info@commaide.com to get help on that front and letingt us know how that eventually pans out.